# Wpf mahapps collapse datagrid row by condition not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I need to hide rows under a certain condition, I do this through a style trigger. But for some reason it doesn't work if you use Map apps styles. If I delete styles from the dictionary, everything works. What i need to do to make it work with Mah app styles as well?

```
 <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsArchive}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
 </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I also tried using baseOn  but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `RowStyle` instead of `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsArchive}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```